# Agrupar e somar array com PHP

Tags: php, array

Preciso saber agrupar e somar um `array`, mas não estou achando como fazer.

```php
$array = array("vermelho", "vermelho", "vermelho", "verde", "azul", "azul");
```

queria um retorno assim

```
3
1
2
```

Ou seja, ele vai agrupar e somar a quantidade de itens iguais.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Exemplo de `array_count_values()`

```php
<?php
$array = array(1, "ola", 1, "mundo", "ola");  
$a = array_count_values($array);  
?>
```

ou o teu:

```php
 $array = array("vermelho", "vermelho", "vermelho", "verde", "azul", "azul");
 $a = array_count_values($array); 
 var_dump($a);
```

O exemplo acima irá imprimir:

```php
Array   
(  
    [1] => 2  
    [ola] => 2   
    [mundo] => 1  
)   
'''
```

http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: Era exatamente isso Flávio, obrigado!

Answer (score 4):

Alternativa ao já mencionado `array_count_values()`:

```php
$array = array("vermelho", "vermelho", "vermelho", "verde", "azul", "azul");

foreach ($array as $item) {
    if(!isset($count[$item])) $count[$item] = 0;
    $count[$item]++;
}

var_dump($count);
```

Nesse caso, dá o mesmo resultado:

```php
array(3) {
  'vermelho' =>
  int(3)
  'verde' =>
  int(1)
  'azul' =>
  int(2)
}
```

Comment: Não creio que seria uma alternativa, já que a função relatada na pergunta anteriormente resolve o problema. Não há necessidade "recriar" o que já está criado. -1