# Como agrupar e somar valores JSON em strings PHP

Tags: php, json

Tenho um arquivo nomeado como *dados.json* estruturado da seguinte maneira:

```
{
  "price_usd": [
    [
      1588464000000,
      10,
      8
    ],
    [
      1588464000000,
      10,
      8
    ],
    [
      1588464000000,
      10,
      8
    ],
    [
      1588464000000,
      3,
      2.8
    ],
    [
      1588550400000,
      3,
      2.8
    ],
    [
      1588550400000,
      3,
      2.8
    ]
  ]
}
```

A primeira variável representa a data de uma venda, a segunda variável o preço de venda do produto, a terceira variável é o preço de compra.

Gostaria de definir em strings do PHP, as três variáveis a seguir com os dados do arquivo em exemplo, onde as datas serão agrupadas e os valores somados:

```
$data = "1588464000000, 1588550400000";
$venda = "33, 6";
$compra = "26.8, 5,6";
```

Para extrair os dados do arquivo utilizo:

```
$JSON = file_get_contents('dados.json');
```

Gostaria de obter as somas dos valores (preço de compra e preço de venda) agrupados pelas datas, ou seja, somar tudo que foi vendido "ontem" e "hoje" por exemplo.

Comment: Até onde escreveu "...a terceira variável é o preço de compra." está claro, a partir do momento em que escreveu "...Gostaria de definir em strings do PHP..." em diante não é compreensível. O que você quer fazer? Colocar `$data`, `venda` e `$compra` num array dentro do seu arquivo JSON?

Comment: @AugustoVasques gostaria de obter as somas dos valores (preço de compra e preço de venda) agrupados pelas datas, ou seja, somar tudo que foi vendido "ontem" e "hoje" por exemplo.

Comment: talun, coloca na pergunta isso que você explicou nos comentários. E coloque um exemplo de como tentou resolver o problema para que eu possa lhe fazer a orientação.

Comment: assim que conseguir adaptar algo que me traga algum resultado atualizo com os exemplos, desculpe mas não consegui ainda. Estou tentando adaptar essas respostas https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/294046/90997, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1745/90997 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/117985/90997

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
//lê o conteúdo e transforma em array
$JSON = json_decode(file_get_contents('dados.json'), true);
//itera sobre os valores
foreach($JSON['price_usd'] as $i) {
    // inicializa os contadores
    if (!array_key_exists($i[0], $agrupados)) {
        $agrupados[$i[0]] = ['venda'=>0, 'compra'=>0];
    }
    $agrupados[$i[0]]['venda'] += $i[1];
    $agrupados[$i[0]]['compra'] += $i[2];
}

$linhaDatas = [];
$linhaVendas = [];
$linhaCompras = [];

foreach ($agrupados as $data => $valores) {
    $linhaDatas[] = $data;
    $linhaVendas[] = $valores['venda'];
    $linhaCompras[] = $valores['compra'];
}

echo implode(', ',$linhaDatas);
echo implode(', ',$linhaVendas);
echo implode(', ',$linhaCompras);
```

Comment: há dias tentando, exatamente o que precisava!